# Encrypted key is differentiations in java and iOS

Tags: java, ios, swift

I used below code for encryption using AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding algorith, function:

```
public static void setKey(String myKey) {
        MessageDigest sha = null;
        try {
            key = myKey.getBytes("UTF-8");
            sha = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
            key = sha.digest(key);
            key = Arrays.copyOf(key, 16);
            secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
//            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
//            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public static String encrypt(String strToEncrypt, String secret) {
        try {
            setKey(secret);
                Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
            return Base64.encodeToString(cipher.doFinal(strToEncrypt.getBytes("UTF-8")), Base64.DEFAULT);
        } catch (Exception e) {
//            System.out.println("Error while encrypting: " + e.toString());
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Output:

```
Meeting ID : 20201228165764
Passcode: 769762

Encrypted values:
 meetingid:   LfD3obeP45AAGXYxPiByvQ==
 passcode:     fcJSdMArO3vUOL/WxwzRfw==
```

I used below AESEncryption code in iOS, but get a different encryption key, function:

```
func AESEncryption(key: String) -> String? {
        let keyData: NSData! = (key as NSString).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue) as NSData!
        let data: NSData! = (self as NSString).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue) as NSData!
        let cryptData    = NSMutableData(length: Int(data.length) + kCCBlockSizeAES128)!
        let keyLength              = size_t(kCCKeySizeAES128)
        let operation: CCOperation = UInt32(kCCEncrypt)
        let algoritm:  CCAlgorithm = UInt32(kCCAlgorithmAES128)
        let options:   CCOptions   = UInt32(kCCOptionECBMode + kCCOptionPKCS5Padding)
        var numBytesEncrypted :size_t = 0
        let cryptStatus = CCCrypt(operation,
                                  algoritm,
                                  options,
                                  keyData.bytes, keyLength,
                                  nil,
                                  data.bytes, data.length,
                                  cryptData.mutableBytes, cryptData.length,
                                  &numBytesEncrypted)
        if UInt32(cryptStatus) == UInt32(kCCSuccess) {
            cryptData.length = Int(numBytesEncrypted)
            var bytes = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: cryptData.length)
            cryptData.getBytes(&bytes, length: cryptData.length)
            var hexString = ""
            for byte in bytes {
                hexString += String(format:"%02x", UInt8(byte))
            }
            return hexString}
      return nil //Check condition nil
    }
```

In android code secret key is generated is different than iOS. Can you please help to get same encrypted key from AES/ECB/PKS5padding algorithm? I am checking with https://8gwifi.org/CipherFunctions.jsp link.

Comment: Kindly edit your post and add sample data for both systems (android / iOS) so we can compare the outputs, thanks.

Comment: Android with above code

text :20201228165764
secret : Tata@123#

Secretkey : 1EVNN6xH8I/qd8rMmClhSQ==
Encrypted Key : cFbx46JOjlK8Q0TpmkOrKg==

Ios code for SHA1 key :
+ (NSData *)sha1HashFromString:(NSString *)stringToHash {
    NSData *stringData = [stringToHash dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    uint8_t digest[CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH] = {16};
    CC_SHA1([stringData bytes], [stringData length], digest);
    NSData *hashedData = [NSData dataWithBytes:digest length:16];
    return hashedData;
}

Get same key as android but encrypted key getting different :

Answer (score 1):

In your Swift code, you're just using the string bytes as-is without hashing.

Note that you shouldn't be using SHA-1 for this; you should be using a [KDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_derivation_function) instead, or (most ideally) a prepackaged library that does all of this error-prone operation for you.

Comment: I am getting secret key same as android but not getting same encrypted key like android in iOS